Calculate Index of Element in Pyramid
I'm currently programming a small website that automates the calculation of Pyramid tournament placements.
Players are ranked in a pyramid like so (the numbers represent the current rank of a player):
           1
          2 3 
         4 5 6
       7 8  9 10
     11 12 13 14 15

The rules are that you can only challenge players that are on the same row to the left and on the above row to the right of the player.
So assuming I'm player 9 i can only challenge player 6,7 and 8.
If I'm player 6 I can only challenge player 4 and 5 (because there's nobody to the right in the above row).
I'm struggling to find a formular that calculates the highest ranked player i can challenge (so reusing the examples above f(9)=6 and f(6) = 4).
floor((n+1)/2) is close but I get an off by one error when I'm on the right side of a row : floor((6+1)/2) = 3 and not 4 as it should be.
Any help for a math newbie like me?

This sequence is defined by $a(n+1) = a(n)$ if $n$ is a triangular number, $a(n+1) = a(n) + 1$ otherwise, also known as A122797 on the OEIS. Not sure there is a closed formula for such a sequence.

You can get the first element on a row $n$ from $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. That should help somewhat ...

This sequence is defined by $a(n+1)=a(n)$ if $n$ is a triangular number, $a(n+1)=a(n)+1$ otherwise, also known as A122797 on the OEIS. Here is a closed formula for your sequence
$$a(n)=n+1-\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}\right\rfloor$$
I used the fact that $a(n)$ and the sequence $b(n)$ defined as A001614 on the OEIS are linked by the formula
$$a(n)=b(n)-n+1$$
But, according to the OEIS,
$$b(n)=2n-\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}{2}\right\rfloor$$
Hence the formula given above.

Even though i don't know why: it works! Thanks :)
